# can i use a mortar shower pan before its tiled

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, mortar

can i take showers in a mortar shower pan, before it is tiled?

I am trying to redo 2 bathrooms at once.  Is it possible to take a showers in one when it is only half complete, and for how long is this OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the shower if your drain is flush with the pan and sealed. You would not want standing soapy water left after showering. If I did this I would etch the pan with a weak Muriatic acid and water solution prior to putting the tile in to remove the soap residue.

Comment: As to the second question... every shower will deposit soap and skin oil on your mortar. The longer you go, the worse that gets. Take that for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

In my locale the code enforcement authority requires the builder to fill the waterproofed pan with water to test and confirm tightness. If your pan was constructed properly it should not leak.

That being said, I would *not* do it for reasons stated by others (soap/oil residue compromising tile adhesion) and because the mortar bed could be damaged by soaking it with water and trampling all over it prior to tiling.